# Mysql inheritance with tables

Tags: java, mysql

I am programming in Java and I have a three classes.

One is `User`. The other classes are `UserTeacher` and `UserStudent`. Both inherit from `User`.

I have to implement tables in a mysql database to store the values. 
What would you do? `User` has the attributes `username`, `pw`, `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: Depending on how much effort you want to put into this, and how extensible it needs to be, you might look at a ORM like Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Make one table with an extra attribute, besides username, pw, firstname, called userType. Was there something else you meant to ask?

Edit. You could also split up the tables into something like:

```
UserTeacher: firstname, passwd, username
UserStudent: firstname, passwd, username
User: firstname, username
```

But I still think the first way is better considering that the teacher and student classes only differ in terms of who they are but not their attributes (well at least not mentioned ones). If you do have a lot of other attributes I'd recomend somethign as follows:

```
UserTeacher: firstname, username, attr1, attr2, attrN
UserStudent: firstname, username, attr1, attr2, attrN
User: firstname, username, passwd
```

Comment: is there really no better way?
if you can see i have something like this:http://s14.directupload.net/images/120612/6zw9oq9q.png
of course table student and teacher will get a lot of attributes later